# Scrape same element from multiple URLs and write into excel

Tags: python

Typing this post in the hope you could help me. My project could be complicated or weird, so I apologize in advance.

I have a textfile including a large list of URLs. Every URL is based on a verb and each site of the URL contains the konjugations of the verb. How can I put all the links in an iteration, so in the spreadsheet each cell contains a verb?

This is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import requests

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

r = requests.get('URL WILL BE HERE', cookies={'COOKIE WILL BE HERE'})
content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

Infinitiv = soup.find_all('a')[44]

wb.save('AlleVerben.xlsx')
```

The textfile containing all 2700 URLs looks like this:

```
https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-abbauen.html
https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-machen.html
https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-gehen.html
https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-lieben.html
https://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-hauen.html
...
```

The spreadsheet should look like this:

A1 should contain "abbauen" (first verb of the URL), A2 "machen" (second), and so on.

For loops are hurting my brain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by opening the text file in your script and reading it line by line. Use `enumerate` in your for loop so that there is a variable that is keeping track of how many loops have happened, so you know which row of the spreadsheet to write to. Enumerate takes a second argument that allows us to specify a starting value. Since there is no zero row of the spreadsheet, pass 1 as the argument so that the counter starts at 1.

In each line, we'll use regular expressions to grab just the part of the URL that you want, the verb. We then write the verb to column "A" row `n`, where `n` is the counter variable we get from enumerate. Using an f-string allows us to quickly substitute `n` into the cell name like this: `cell = f"A{n}"`

```py
import re
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open("verb_file.txt", "r") as verb_file: # Open the text file. Change the name to match the file.
    for n, line in enumerate(verb_file, 1): # Read the file line by line
        verb = re.search(r"deutsch-verb-([\w]+)\.html", line).group(1)
        # The regex pattern used here grabs everything between "deutsch-verb-" and ".html"
        ws[f"A{n}"] = verb # Assign the verb to the cell
        # We used enumerate (starting with 1) in the for loop to keep track
        # of how many loops we've done, so we know which cell to write to.
wb.save('AlleVerben.xlsx')
```